# powershell script fails to create Excel pivot table filter

Tags: excel, powershell, filter

I am trying to set a filter value in an Excel pivot table in PowerShell and for more than I try things and research the topic, I can't make it work. My code looks as follows:

```
$ExcelWorkbook.Worksheets[1].PivotTables("pivHealthStatus").PivotFields("machineTags")
                            .PivotFilters.Add2($xlCaptionEquals,"my whatever tag")
```

and I always get the "Value does not fall within the expected range." message.

My pivot looks like this:

[image]

I have read also other threads but nobody seems to make it work in Powershell.

By running the command above I would expect the "machinesTags" filter to show machines that include that tag. I have tried with both Add and Add2, same error message.